# String Java code checks

Tags: java

I want to optimize Java source code. I implemented this code for file download:

```
if (!file.exists())
        {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "No file " + reportPath);
            return;
        }

        if (!file.canWrite())
        {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Can't write in file " + reportPath);
            return;
        }

        if (!file.canRead())
        {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Can't read file " + reportPath);
            return;
        }
```

How I can make it a lot more compact?

Comment: You can write a method for it but sometimes readability is more important than reducing number of lines.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I agree but can I shrink it with if-else refactoring?

Comment: It depends whether you need to write all 3 if statements just one after the other or at different places. It they are at different places then i think it's write.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think below answers explained it, however if you want to make it more unreadable you can go for ternary operator ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can swap to an if-else, and then take advantage of the implicit returning at the end of a method scope.

```
public void doThing(Object response) {
  if (!file.exists()) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "No file " + reportPath);
  } else if (!file.canWrite()) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Can't write in file " + reportPath);
  } else if (!file.canRead()) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Can't read file " + reportPath);
  } else {
    doStuff();
  }
  // Implicit return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like this:

```
boolean check(boolean condition, HttpServletResponse response, int code, String message) {
  if (!condition) {
    response.sendError(code, message);
  }
  return condition;
}
```

And then invoke like:

```
if (!check(file.exists(), response, SC_NOT_FOUND, "No file " + reportPath)
    || !check(file.canWrite(), response, SC_NOT_AUTHORIZED, "Can't write " + reportPath)
    || Etc) {
  return;
}
```

But I don't think this really helps readability.

Answer (score 0):

I know i have increased the number of lines here, but i think this version can easily accommodate adding more conditions or deleting existing conditions in future, with code changes to be made at less places.

```
boolean isFileExist = file.exists();
boolean isFileRead = file.canWrite();
boolean isFileWrite = file.canRead();

if (!isFileExist) {
  setError(response, 0, "No file " + reportPath);
} else if (!isFileRead) {
  setError(response, 1, "Can't read file " + reportPath);
} else if (!isFileWrite) {
  setError(response, 1, "Can't write in file " + reportPath);
} else {
  setError(response, 2, "Error file " + reportPath);
}

private void setError(HttpServletResponse response, int type, String message) {
    switch (type) {
       case 0:
           response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, message);
           break;
       case 1:
           response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message);
           break;
       default:
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Java8:**

The `if` conditions can be hidden with a Map defined as

`Map<Predicate<File>, Consumer<HttpServletResponse>>`

However, since `response.sendError` throws an IOException, we cannot use a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) here. So, I'm creating a functional interface similar to `Consumer` but that would throw an IOException.

```
public interface MyConsumer<T> {
   void accept(T t) throws IOException;
}
```

This map holds the mapping between the Predicate (condition) and the action.

```
Map<Predicate<File>, MyConsumer<HttpServletResponse>> conditionActionMap
                              = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //Order matters here
conditionActionMap.put(file -> !file.exists(),
            response -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "No file " + reportPath));
conditionActionMap.put(file -> !file.canWrite(),
            response -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Can't write in file " + reportPath));
conditionActionMap.put(file -> !file.canRead(),
            response -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,  "Can't read file " + reportPath));


Optional<MyConsumer<HttpServletResponse>> optionalConsumer = conditionActionMap
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().apply(file))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst();

if (optionalConsumer.isPresent()) {
    optionalConsumer.get().accept(response);
} else {
    //rest of method not shown in OP
}
```

---

If the above `else` block also involves doing some operation with the HttpServletResponse (and your original method does not return anything), then you can create a `MyConsumer<HttpServletResponse>` for the success case.

```
MyConsumer<HttpServletResponse> successConsumer = response -> response.setStatus(200); //or whatever

MyConsumer<HttpServletResponse> consumer = conditionActionMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().apply(file))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(successConsumer);
consumer.accept(response);
```